# PHP Table Checkbox Problem - how to properly quote name for checkbox with array when echo-ing?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details  ORDER BY Hostname ASC     ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);



                echo "<table>";

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> <b>Checkbox </b> </td>";
                echo "<td> <b>ID </b> </td>";
                echo "<td> <b>Make and Model</b> </td>";
                echo "<td> <b>Serial Number</b> </td>";
                echo "<td> <b>Windows Key</b></td>";
                echo "<td> <b>Status</b> </td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                    // output data of each row
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>
                        <td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['MakeAndModel'] . "</td>
                        <td>" .  $row['SerialNumber'] .  "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['WindowsKey'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
```

I am echo-ing a checkbox at the most left column of every row of data that gets selected from the SQL command. The checkboxes appear all right.

[image: successful checkboxes appearing 1 per row]

The problem comes with getting the checkbox data. From understanding each checkbox holds an ID. I want to click a button and retrieve a list of IDs from the checked checkboxes.

So I have a button

```
    <form action="checkout-computer-1.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="checkout" id="checkout" value="Checkout selected computers" /><br />
            </form>
```

Currently got it linked to another .php file and in this other php file I have the following code:

```
  85   if(isset($_POST['checkout'])) {
  86                      echo "Test1";
  87                      $checkboxVariable = $_POST['checkbox'];
  88                      foreach($checkboxVariable as $id) {
  89                          echo "Test2";
  90                      }
  91                  }
```

This is what gets display on my screen after clicking on the button

```
    Test1

Warning: Undefined array key "checkbox" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ylam\checkout-computer-1.php on line 87

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ylam\checkout-computer-1.php on line 88
```

So the button is working. However retrieving a list of IDs from the checked checkboxes cannot. The undefined array key error leads me to believe my lack of understanding of when to use single quotation and double quotation in echo statements to be the problem. Specifically this line:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='".$row['ID']."'></td>
```

Comments please.

Comment: Make sure the checkboxes are inside the same form as the submit button. Only form elements (inputs, selects, textareas, buttons) that are inside `<form ...> your inputs </form>` will be submitted with the form so just open the form before the table and close it after. Right now you're only submitting the button, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed moving the entire PHP code chunk into the form resolved the problem I was facing. Nothing to do with quotations.